# HTML5 Video Controlling Poster Image via Javascript

Tags: html, html5-video

I am trying to show the poster image once the video ends and here is the code. However the poster image is not showing up. Any clues why this is not happening?

The ideal steps would be
1. Pause video
2. Init at first frame
3. Remove default controls
4. Show poster image.

Code:

```
document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("ended", function () {
    document.getElementById("video1").pause();
    document.getElementById("video1").currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById("video1").removeAttribute("controls");
    document.getElementById("video1").setAttribute("poster", "graphic.jpg");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("ended", function () {
    this.load()
});
```

Comment: this did not work for me...I have a video tag - using Rails 4 - and would like the poster to appear if the video is paused, stopped, and when it ends. Any ideas?